# Gulp compile problems with mac m1 gulp-notify and node-notify errors

Tags: webpack, gulp, gulp-notify, node-notifier

I have macbook pro m1
i am using gulp with webpack for wp project to compile code.

i get this error

```
[16:28:42] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin "gulp-notify"
Message:
    spawn Unknown system error -86
Details:
    errno: -86
    code: Unknown system error -86
    syscall: spawn
```

on macbook air m1 it works

I deleted gulp-notify and node-notify and now it works.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a m3 pro max, I excluded the gulp notify from my gulp dev and production scripts in order to continue and plugin... so I ended up like this:

```js
.pipe(notify({
  message: pumped("Fonts Moved"),
  onLast: true
}))
```

You will not have the notifier but you may want to use this:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

Gulp exec will notifiy you by saying font dev mode ready, for example:

```js
// Include this at the start of the script
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// ...your code here 

// in module exports, add this before the return
exec('say fonts dev mode ready', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
});
```